# Residue Theorem for a self-intersecting closed curve?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, residue-calculus, quantum-field-theory

What does the residue theorem say about a closed curve curve as shown in this figure: [figure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335414/wick-rotation-contour-doesnt-seem-to-be-simply-connected)

It seems to me that this curve self intersect at origin.

It's related to the Wick rotation and I can't close the $[-\infty, \infty]$ contour in a proper way so that the residues inside are zero, please see link for description of poles and contour.

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Why can't you split the contour into 2 contours, each a simple closed curve enclosing an arc within a quadrant of the complex plane?

Comment: yes I've thought about that, didn't do the calculation though (lazy me). Perhaps this is the way to go. How about the origin, they will touch there, does that interfere at all?

Comment: No, unless there is a pole at the origin.  In that case, you would indent the contours to avoid the origin in the first place.

Comment: This problem is solved. Solution is to consider two quarter circles just as Ron Gordon proposed.

Thanks for your help Ron!

(Why is it so hard to put this in a QFT book and get it over with, instead of just saying, rotate this and rotate that!!?? aargh!)

Comment: I'll post my comment as an answer so you can close this one out.

Comment: O.K. perfect Ron. Now I just have to figure out how to close it out.

Comment: Just press the accept checkmark next to my answer.  Feel free to upvote it as well!

Comment: Thanks again Ron! May science bless you.

Comment: It has, Noob, it has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the contour into 2 contours, each a simple closed curve enclosing an arc within a quadrant of the complex plane.